# To make a LoadBalancer service internal on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Do you know what is the annotation that we can use it on GKE to make a LoadBalancer service internal?. For example Azure (and AWS) supports the following annotation (shown in the YAML code snippet) to make a LoadBalancer service internal. I couldn’t find equivalent of it on GKE. For example naturally one may expect **gcp-load-balancer-internal** as the equivalent annotation on GKE; unfortunately it is not. Here is the Azure and AWS documentation for it, I am looking equivalent of it on GKE.

- [Azure: internal LoadBalancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb)
- [AWS: annotations](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/service/annotations/)

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing#create).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ilb-service
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
  labels:
    app: hello
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: hello
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 annotations:

For GKE versions 1.17 and later, use the annotation:

```
networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
```

For earlier versions, use the annotation:

```
cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
```

Plus, I’m sharing with you some GCP’s helpful official documentation in the following URLs [Using an internal TCP/UDP load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing) and [Setting up Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/setting-up-l7-internal?hl=en#configure-a-network) .